# Equating time values in IF statement

Tags: vba, excel

Good morning,

I am having an issue whereby logical statements regarding time values are not evaluating as expected.

Is there a known issue with equating recurring decimals logically?

For clarity here is a sample of the code in question.

```
Function compareTimes(timeCurrent, timeStart, timeEnd, timeBreak1, Optional timeLunch As Variant, Optional timeBreak2 As Variant)

    If timeCurrent >= timeStart And timeCurrent < timeEnd Then

        If timeCurrent = timeBreak1 Or timeCurrent = timeBreak2 Then
            compareTimes = "b"
        ElseIf IsMissing(timeLunch) = False Then
             timeLunchEnd = timeLunch + (1 / 48)

             If timeCurrent >= timeLunch And timeCurrent < timeLunchEnd Then
                 compareTimes = "L"
             Else
                 compareTimes = 1
             End If

        Else
             compareTimes = 1
        End If

    Else
        compareTime = 0
    End If

End Function
```

All arguments of the function are Excel times in the form h:mm.
An example of the error is the 2nd If statement - when timeCurrent and timeBreak1 are the same cell in Excel, the function outputs "b" as expected.
But if timeCurrent and timeBreak1 are in different cells with same value (e.g 12:00) it returns 1 instead.

Any help on understanding logicals and floating points would be much appreciated.

Comment: put in `Debug.Print CDbl(timeCurrent); CDbl(timeBreak1)` just above the comparison. Are the display numbers the same?

Answer (score 0):

Though you may be showing the time as h:mm, Excel actually stores the full value including seconds.  If you change the cell formatting to h:mm:ss, the values may not be "identical" as assumed. Times are stored as Date.Time where, numbers before the decimal represent days and those after the decimal represent the fractional part of a 24 hour day (ie 0.5 = 12:00 noon). Try changing the formatting of the cells to show date and time just to be sure the entire "date value" is consistent with your expectations.

The variables for time should be defined as double to ensure there are no issues with the data types being considered. It's not clear how the time is entered.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Think I may have worked it out by combining your two tips. When using the Debug.Print output I noticed that the figures for midday were not identical - out by 2e-11. When I thought about the difference I realised that the timeCurrent times were generated on the spreadsheet with a fill handle, but the other time(Vars) were input manually.
Re-typed timeCurrent and now it works.

Thanks a lot for the tips that pointed me in the right direction.